# how can i call index action of default controller from my generated controller or how can i render index view from my controller?

Tags: grails, controller, indexing

I am not getting how can I render index view of default controller from my generated controller action.

Is there any way to do that in grails. Please let me know.

With advance thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several way to do that. The simplest case is that you should name your view according to the controller/action that handle it.

For example, if your controller is `HomeController` with action `index`, your view should be `/view/home/index.gsp`. This's called Grails philosophy - Convention Over Configuration.

If you want to make an action render a specific view, you can use [render](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html) command.

You should easily figure it out with the [Grails document - Web layer](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.%20The%20Web%20Layer).